# Поиск названия таблиц в столбцах которых встречаются определенные данные

Tags: postgresql

Необходимо найти таблицы в столбцах которых встречаются определенные данные

Есть запрос

```
--Удаляем таблицу если она есть
DROP TABLE if exists "cm_name" CASCADE;
--Создаём временную таблицу
create temp table cm_name (
        tab_name varchar,
        col_name varchar,
        full_name varchar GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('public'||'.'||tab_name||'.'||col_name)stored);
        
--Добавляем в нее данные
insert into cm_name (tab_name, col_name)
SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','pg_catalog') and data_type = 'character varying';

select * from cm_name;
--Циклом проходим по таблице выбирая название таблицы в которой содержится текст (sword)
DO $$
DECLARE 
    col varchar;
    sword varchar = '%index.html?id=a58f23596fbd470c87a4d16eec0a53ab%';
Begin
for col in (SELECT col_name FROM cm_name )
Loop
    Raise Notice 'tablename = %',
    (SELECT tab_name FROM cm_name where col like sword);
END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

который выводит следующее

> NOTICE:  tablename = NULL  NOTICE:  tablename = NULL  NOTICE:
> tablename = NULL и тд

Где может быть допущена ошибка ?

Comment: Ну у тебя то tab_name то table_name

Comment: То col_name  то column_name

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  эти столбцы в 2 разных таблицах

Comment: Вы сравниваете наименование столбца с переменной sword. ``where col like sword``. Результат ``null`` - это правильно. Вам нужен динамический SQL запрос для поиска.